Grafana - Create ServiceNow incident via url
I have an grafana dashboard and want to create an servicenow incident, by url or button.
Anyone know if is possible in a grafana dashboard create an incident on service now, via url or api?
Search online to create icd via url, but found nothing.

You can use the ServiceNow table API and send a post request: https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/xanadu-api-reference/page/integrate/inbound-rest/concept/c_TableAPI.html#title_table-POST
